# Mail enabling an AD account too soon after creation

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory, exchange-server, directoryservices

I'm using the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` library to create an AD user account, then soon after using a PowerShell runspace to run the `Enable-Mailbox` command.

When I run this, it is **sometimes** failing on the Mail-Enable with the error "*Active Directory account must be logon-enabled for the user's mailbox.*"

If rerun the same code, but just try to Mail-Enable the account only, it works fine. And again, other times it's able to create the AD account and Mail-Enable.

This link suggests that AD is still configuring the account when Exchange tries to mail-enable it:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/d53d91fd-c479-40e4-9791-32cb5da24721?prof=required

Here is the runspace code:

```
var connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PSExchangeURI"]), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PSExchangeShellURI"], new PSCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Username"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"].ToSecureString()));
connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos;

var command = new Command("Enable-Mailbox");
command.Parameters.Add("Identity", userPrincipal.UserPrincipalName);
command.Parameters.Add("Alias", userPrincipal.SamAccountName);
command.Parameters.Add("DisplayName", userPrincipal.DisplayName);
command.Parameters.Add("Database", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExchangeDatabase"]);

using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo)) {
    using (var pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline()) {
        runspace.Open();
        pipeline.Commands.Add(command);

        var results = pipeline.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Is there something else I can do to avoid this error (besides introducing a thread sleep)?

Comment: I don't see any question here.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was concentrating so much on communicating the problem, that I forgot the question! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are seeing is likely to be down to replication time lag and the exchange server talking to a different DC then the AD user creation code.

What you should do is to line up exchange and your AD creation code to talk to the same DC.

From the *PrincipalContext* object under *S.DS.AM* read the DC's FQDN from the *ConnectedServer* property. Then pass in that value to the *-DomainController* parameter to the enable-mailbox cmdlet.

Comment: Great suggestion. I will try it out and come back to report. I was wary of specifying the DC before hand for both processes (in case DC names change in the future) - but your solution still allows me to just specify the domain.

Comment: Hi Chris. Did it work for you? I have the same problem. Regards Martin

Comment: I also have the same problem, can you provide feedback on your experience?

Answer (score 0):

So I solve the "hard coding" issue of the DC by declaring a **$dchostname** variable in my code at run time.  It queries the domain to find a suitable DC and then all processes in my script use that domain.  This way even if I replace all my DCs, I don't have to update my code.

```
#Domain Controller Information
$dcs = (Get-ADDomainController -Filter *)
$dc = $dcs | Where {$_.OperationMasterRoles -like "*RIDMaster*"}
$dchostname = $dc.HostName
```